# IOException when using .Net Core File Upload (Streaming)

Tags: asp.net-core

Update 12/08/2017, the Github issue has now been updated with the resolution to the below issue, see the comment from ardalis: [3691](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/3691)

I've been trying to get file stream working in .NET Core MVC using information from Microsoft's Sample;
[FileUploadSample](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/mvc/models/file-uploads/sample/FileUploadSample)

But with no success in a pure .Net Core MVC (as the sample for streaming uses Angular bindings, which is not what I'm using).

This [Test File Streaming Repo](https://github.com/aaron-bozit/Testing.DotNetCore.FileUploadStreaming) contains the bare minimum code to reproduce the issue I've received.

The user navigates to *TestFileUpload/Views/Streaming/Index.cshtml* they will enter some details and select the file to upload. The user will then submit the form;

```
<form asp-area="" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Streaming" asp-action="StreamUpload" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData[ "ReturnUrl" ]" id="submit-file-form" method="post">
    <input name="CurriculumVitae" type="file" id="file" />
    <button type="submit">Create User</button>
</form>
```

The form then calls within: *TestFileUpload/Controllers/StreamingController.cs*

```
public async Task< IActionResult > StreamUpload() {
    ...
    var reader = new MultipartReader( boundary, HttpContext.Request.Body );
    var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
    ...
}
```

But, I then receive the error *"IOException: Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component."*

```
TestFileUpload.Controllers.StreamingController+<StreamUpload>d__2.MoveNext() in StreamingController.cs

            51. var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
```